# A question about constructing relatives from existential sentences

Tags: relative-clauses, existential-constructions

[Chomsky (2004)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRPmJ.jpg) claims that examples very similar to (1a) and (1b) are crashingly bad. But I was wondering if the (somewhat wordier) versions in (2a) and (2b) are equally degraded, or if there is a noticeable improvement in acceptability and intelligibility.

> (1a) He's that one guy (that) there were delivered to the office several pictures of
>
> (1b) He's that one artist (that) there had arrived in the mail some books about

> (2a) He's that one guy (that) there were likely to be delivered to the office several pictures of
>
> (2b) He's that one artist (that) there seemed to us to have arrived in the mail some books about

Comment: Why do you think they'd be any better?

Comment: No, they're still awful. Though the suspicion is justified, because of Zwicky's Law, which says that the more irrelevant garbage you put in a sentence, the better it sounds. I suspect it's because of parser fatigue. Note (I spose Chomsky did also) that it's the _there_-insertion and its subsequent movement of the subject to the end that causes the star -- _He's that one guy (that) several pictures of were delivered to the office_ is OK.

Comment: Why would you think that changing *were delivered* to *were likely to be delivered* would make the sentence acceptable?

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes,  *He's the one guy there's a photo of* is ok. And note that *He's the one guy that we delivered to the office several pictures of* seems marginal. Postposing an object with a missing last word/gap at the end seems to be problematic there.

Answer (score 1):

As John Lawler commented:

> No, they're still awful. Though the suspicion is justified, because of Zwicky's Law, which says that the more irrelevant garbage you put in a sentence, the better it sounds. I suspect it's because of parser fatigue. Note (I spose Chomsky did also) that it's the *there*-insertion and its subsequent movement of the subject to the end that causes the star -- *He's that one guy (that) several pictures of were delivered to the office* is OK.

For my part, I'm a bit skeptical about that last claim, particularly if you omit the *that.* To me "He's that one guy several pictures of were delivered to the office" sounds quite bad also.